# How do I test in app purchases before deploying the backend with Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, in-app-purchase

I have successfully released in app purchases for ios where it is possible to do sandbox subscriptions with a local development device.

With Android however it seems that to be able to test subscriptions the app has to be in at least the closed test track first. I guess that this means that the app needs to go through review as well before I am able to test subscriptions?

With ios I was able to verify that my backend was responding correctly to the subscriptions locally before deploying anything. How can I do this with Android? I would like to run the app against my local backend to verify the backend calls before deploying the api to production. Is this even possible?

My idea was to build and release a version of the app to the closed track with my local ip as backend url, but if it has to go through review I guess that it won't work, since the app wont function properly without a backend.

How is this usually solved?